# How to Pass an authorization-token-header in an integration-test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

A [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041091/ror-testing-an-action-that-uses-http-token-authentication)
implies that I can test a request with token authentication, in my
intergration tests, as follows:

```
get "/v1/sites", nil, :authorization => "foo"
assert_response :success
```

For some reason, the headers don't get to my application:

```
get "/v1/sites", nil, :authorization => "foo"
assert_match response.headers, /foo/

Expected {"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "X-UA-Compatible"=>"chrome=1", "WWW-Authenticate"=>"Token realm=\"Application\"", "Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8", "Cache-Control"=>"no-cache", "X-Request-Id"=>"23915302-9cfe-424d-86fe-5d60bc0d6b2c", "X-Runtime"=>"0.054857", "Content-Length"=>"27"} to match /foo/.
```

The authorization-header does not get through, which I can confirm when placing a `throw response.headers` in the controller. When I
test with e.g. curl, I *do* see the header coming through. And there I
can even set the token and get access. The relevant code from the
controller is:

```
module V1
  class SitesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :restrict_access, :only => :index

    def index
      head :success
    end

    private
    def restrict_access
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
        token == "foo"
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

This is minitest, on Rails 4, using
[Rails-API](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api)

For reference, here is the Middleware stack, it is a lot slimmer then most default Rails apps.

```
use ActionDispatch::Static
use Rack::Lock
use #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x992cd28>
use Rack::Runtime
use ActionDispatch::RequestId
use Rails::Rack::Logger
use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
use ActionDispatch::Reloader
use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
use Rack::Head
use Rack::ConditionalGet
use Rack::ETag
run MyApp::Application.routes
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for reference. Everything was right, I was just being stupid and **testing the wrong thing** while debugging:

```
assert_match response.headers, /foo/
```

Is obviously false, because this is the **response**. Correct is to test the **request**

```
get "/v1/sites", nil, :authorization => %{Token token="foo"}
assert_includes request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"], "foo"
```

This passes just fine.

Comment: For Rails 5/5.1 use the `headers:` keyword argument (no need for nil). 
`get "/v1/sites", headers: { "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" => "Token token=1111" }`

Answer (score 0):

You can set an header on the request object just before performing you request.

```
request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'foo'
get '/v1/sites'
assert_response :success
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. In IntegrationTest, both `request` and `@request` are not set or available: both are nil. This /does/ work with ControllerTests, though.

Comment: You're right sorry, I was thinking of controller tests. The code you mentioned should work with ActionDispatch::Integration::ResquestHelpers (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get), are you using it?

Comment: It seems I am calling _that_ method, yes. `self.method(:get).owner` reports `ActionDispatch::Integration::Runner`.